# create new roles in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, user-roles

I have created a database system for a cms for a news website. I want to have only 4 roles in my db system : Admin, Author, Editor and Guest ( who only read the web pages). But there are some pre-defined roles in every db system like sys and db_owner and… and they are not removable but I want the only 4 roles I mentioned above. How can I aim this goal? thanks

Comment: **Please:** use the [sql-server] tag instead of [sql] and [server] separately - thanks! Makes it easier to find and catalog your questions....

Answer (score 0):

ah, you cannot!

Also I do not think you will need to tweak the database system. Rather, architect a good solution for your application/frontend/website.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i am aware, you can't modify those roles (besides adding logins to them).  instead of working around them, you could try using them, it might make life a little bit easier.